# Firestore allows the creation of two separate documents with the same ID in a collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire2

I found out today that you can create 2 different objects in a collections with the same ID.
Initially, I was trying to update an existing document whose ID is some-id like so

```
const ref = this.db.doc(`collectionName/some-id`);
await ref.set(obj, {merge: true});
```

obj here is subset of what the object on the server contains.
I wanted originally to add a new property to the existing object.

I ended up with two different objects with the same ID. One is the old one I had already, and the other is the one I tried to merge with the existing one.

How is it possible that Google Firestore allows duplicate ID in a collection?
Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It's not possible.  Please edit the question to illustrate more specifically what you're observing, so that we can all agree on what actually happened.

Comment: Yes you are right. I described what happened as a solution and what to do to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution after I posted the question.
I have a form from which a user can create an object and choose its ID.

There was a white space in the ID input which did not appear in the Fire store console. which gives the impression they are the same.

Moral of the story: Run a trim() on your IDs if you allow the user to input the ID of a document.

Comment: Better moral: don't let users create document ID's.  It's extremely likely to be very inefficient - not well randomized and distributed for good indexing, for example.  MUCH MUCH better to let Firestore create the ID's, and add the user choice as a field in the document.

Comment: Well it is not allowed for endusers. only admins who need to create objects with specific Ids so we can query them directly later on. But yeah, even with cautious users, human error is to be expected

Comment: There is absolutely no need to hand-create a document ID to be able find it, since you can query on any field. let the "user" (even admin) input be a field in the document - there's no need to ever actually *show* it to any user; just use it for query.  Let Firestore do it's thing.

Comment: I never said it's necessary. It is a design choice to choose IDs as emails to avoid duplicates for exemple, then query a user directly as doc('users/someEmail@gmail.com') which returns one single object instead of collections('users').where('email','==','someEmail')

Comment: Again, not really a design choice - The distribution of IDs is absolutely critical and fundamental to how Firestore is able to scale.  I guarantee you will severely degrade the performance-at-scale of a Firestore app if you insist on using emails as a document ID.  AND IT IS NO LESS EFFICIENT to check for the existence of a document by Query than by using .doc().  SO: no benefits, and many many bad consequences. Why would you insist on doing it that way?

Comment: If you check Firebase documentation, they always set the ID manually in there own examples. Not sure how it will degrade performance. it is just a string after all just like the automatically generated ID. The other reason is it makes it easier to write security rules to allow access to a resource. you can check the ID of the document against the email or the person trying to access it. writing such a rule is much easier than manipulating the data. not to mention if you have collections nested within. But If you have solid proof on how it will degrade performance, I am more than happy to read

Comment: I think this should be an edit in question itself rather than a solution.